# Servo does not keep its position once it does no longer receive a signal from gpizero

Tags: gpio, servo

Following [gpiozero.readthedocs.io](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#servo) I managed to move a servo which in turn opens a (model) toll-gate by winding up a wire. However, the behavior is rather unexpected - as soon as I stop sending a `servo.value`, the servo moves back to its default position.

Here is my code:

```py
from gpiozero import Servo
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
from time import sleep

factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='192.168.1.103')
servo = Servo(19, pin_factory=factory) 

def open_servo():
    # slowly open gate
    for i in range (-20, 20):
        servo.value = i/20
        sleep(0.1)
    # Workaround to keep gate open for 3s
    for i in range (0, 3):
        servo.value = 1
        sleep(1)
    # servo.value = None

def close_servo():
    for i in range (20, -20, -1):
        servo.value = i/20
        sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("My first servo test.")
    open_servo()          # slowly opens gate and keeps it open for 3s
    sleep(2)              # I want the gate to be open another 2s, but the gate closes unexpectedly
    close_servo() # ...just to quickly jump open again and slowly close
```

I also was told by a colleague that I should `servo.value = None` to avoid the explained phenomenon, but that that does not seem to have any effect. **Is it possible to keep the servo at the maximal position without constantly sending signals to my Raspberry Pi? If so, how can I do that?**

Comment: That is how servos work!

Comment: @Milliways Thanks for confirming my hypothesis, and that I now have an official reference for that :-)

Comment: Odd.  Most hobby servos stay in the last commanded position (unless a force is acting on them).

Comment: In your workaround you send the max value 1 and then wait 1 sec. In the time you do not send new values to the servo. So for me there is no difference to the case where you wait outside of the open_servo function (except the time (2sec) you wait).

Comment: Ah, if you don't want to keep Rpi busy looping, try this:https://www.adafruit.com/product/815.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer: I thought so as well, but strangely it does.

Comment: `winding up a wire` ... what kind of a servo are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servos require a constant input to retain their position.

(You can of course remove power to the servo thus preventing it from moving with no input but this is a kludge.)

The servo input does not need to come from an active foreground process.

You can spawn a background process to supply the requisite input and launch processes to modify the background process.

Just to be clear the PWM signal will continue to output the value set.
The problem is [gpiozero resets GPIO state on program exit](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-gpiozero-equivalent-of-gpio-cleanup) so the process needs to be kept running.

Computers don't mind doing something forever!

Comment: I do not expect that the PWM signal would stop, only because the position was not constantly written to the `.value` attribute. I would expect, that the Servo Object keeps sending the respective PWM ratio as long as the `.value` attribute has a value in the rage of -1, 1. And as far as it is still in a pause period, when the misbehavior occurs, I expect the process is still running.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer You are correct that PWM signal will continue until reset - thus continuously providing input to the servo BUT AFAIK gpiozero resets GPIO state on program exit. You can pause the program, but it is better to put this in a background process. I concede all my work on servos has been in c.

Comment: @Milliways I am not familiar with threading in Python (yet), I just started reading xhttps://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ - could you give me a hint how I could refactor my program to have a background-keep-gate-open thread, please?

Comment: I did not mention threading - indeed threading is complex - especially so in Python due to its GIL. More to the point there is no reason you can use simple process control. You can start a program as a background process by including a "&" at the end of the line.

Comment: gpiozero is an excellent tool (even if the documentation is not clear). One significant limitation is that on exit it restores all GPIO to the state they were on entry. (IMO this should be PROMINENTLY mentioned in the documentation). The PWM signal will continue until changed but you need to stop the process from exiting - this can be done with pause (which is mentioned in the documentation). This may not be the best approach, but as it unclear exactly what you want your program to do it is difficult to suggest other approaches.

Comment: I should mention that the loop `for i in range (0, 3):` is unnecessary the PWM will remain - you just need sleep(3) (although this is not an approach I would use)